# MySQL decode Unicode to UTF-8 function

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, utf-8

I want to decode Unicode strings to UTF-8 when inserting in a table. Here's what I have:

```
('\u0645\u064e\u062b\u0652\u0646\u064e\u0649 \u00a0\u062c \u0645\u064e\u062b\u064e\u0627\u0646\u064d')
```

So I want these values to be converted to UTF-8, for example:

```
INSERT INTO `nouns`(`NOUNID`, `WORDID`, `SINGULAR`, `PLURAL`) VALUES (781, 3188, '\u0646\u064e\u062c\u0652\u0645', ('\u0646\u064e\u062c\u0652\u0645'))
```

I am migrating my h2 database to MySQL, so I got this when scripting my h2 db:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.NOUNS(NOUNID, WORDID, SINGULAR, PLURAL) VALUES
  (1, 5, STRINGDECODE('\u0623\u0628\u0651 '), STRINGDECODE
  ('\u0623\u0624\u064f\u0628\u0651')),
  (2, 9, STRINGDECODE('\u0623\u064e\u0628\u0627\u0628'), ''),
```

---

basicly thees \u0623\u0632\u0651 are arabic charchters in unicode representation and I want to convert them in real arabic characters, to be stored like that in database.
I was trying convert function, but because I am new to mysql I couldn't achive this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(_ucs2'\u0623' USING utf8);
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure to get it: you want to store arabic characters under the arabic collation in your database, instead of the utf-8 format, is that so?

Comment: in database there will be arabic letters as well as latin letters,
current coalition for database is coalition unicode_ci

Comment: this is good, you should keep it this way I think.

Comment: but I got in table field \u0623\u064e\u0628\u0627\u0628 but instead of that I want Arabic actual letters.
U+0624 => ؤ, U+0628 => ب, U+062E => خ
see here:
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1536

Comment: why would you want such thing? the client application will understand it if you setup the encoding as utf8

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no built-in function to decode unicode escapes in MySQL, but you can create one; see below:

Note that the backslash is an escape character in MySQL, so you'll need to double them when you write SQL: `'\\u0623\\u064e\\u0628\\u0627\\u0628'`

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION STRINGDECODE(str TEXT CHARSET utf8)
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare pos int;
declare escape char(6) charset utf8;
declare unescape char(3) charset utf8;
set pos = locate('\\u', str);
while pos > 0 do
    set escape = substring(str, pos, 6);
    set unescape = char(conv(substring(escape,3),16,10) using ucs2);
    set str = replace(str, escape, unescape);
    set pos = locate('\\u', str, pos+1);
end while;
return str;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: If you are using a client that uses `;` as the statement delimiter, you have to change the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired on @Joni's answer, and just in case you don't want to use functions, I put it all together in one query. The drawback is that you have to execute the query several times, since on every execution only one 'character' by row get transformed.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET content = REPLACE(
  content,
  SUBSTRING(content, locate('\\u', content), 6),
  CHAR(CONV(SUBSTRING(content, LOCATE('\\u', content) + 2, 4), 16, 10)  using 
  ucs2)) 
WHERE content like '%\\u0%';
```