# How to convert latin characters to their corresponding unicode escape sequences in MySql?

Tags: mysql, encoding

First let me tell you that the character set and collation I'm using is utf8_general_ci.

I have two tables, A and B, for the sake of example.

Table A has a column (let's call it 'columnX'). In any row of table A columnX might have a value that contains latin characters, e.g., 'niño' (means 'boy' in english).

Table B has a column (let's call it 'columnY') that I know might contain 'niño' as part of its value, e.g., 'es un niño bueno' ('he is a good boy' in english), but the 'ñ' will be escaped, since I know columnY contains JSON strings so that string literal would be encoded as 'es un ni\u00f1o bueno'.

I need to find all rows of table A whose column A.columnX is contained in any B.columnY. I need a function that converts al A.columnX in its corresponding escaped version. Something along the lines of the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B
  ON B.columnY LIKE CONCAT('%', escapeUtf8(A.columnX) ,'%')
```

I have tried using `QUOTE`, `CONVERT`, `CAST` and also googles a lot, but all I've found is the opposite to what I need (the posts explain how to convert escaped sequences to something readable by humans).

Thanks in advance,

```
 Adrián
```

Comment: Bump! Does anybody know at least a function such as that exists? Thanks :)

Comment: Oh! Also, a unescape function would work if I reverse `LIKE` comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround

What I did was to use the STRINGDECODE function that I found here (look at Joni's answer): [MySQL decode Unicode to UTF-8 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062330/mysql-decode-unicode-to-utf-8-function) and I used it to "reverse" the query.

Instead of escaping the column with "ñ" (or accented letters, etc.) from table A, I unescaped  the escaped columns in table B with STRINGDECODE.

Also, since I needed to use the decoded column values several times, I stored B.columnY in a temporary table (after applying STRINGDECODE, of course) for later use. This would be the sample code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sanitizedB
SELECT STRINGDECODE(columnY) as sanitizedColumnY, columnZ 
FROM B;

SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN sanitizedB SB
  ON SB.sanitizedColumnY LIKE CONCAT('%', A.columnX ,'%')
```

Of course, I added other columns that I needed too for later use.

It's worth saying that the B table had less than 10.000 records, so the creation of the the temporary table was quite fast... Possibly is not the best solution, but worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing `ñ` as hex `C3B1` in a utf8 column.  Check by doing `SELECT HEX(col) ...`.  If it is `&...;` (there are about 3 possible ways to represent the "html entity"), then you have a mess that should be fixed when `INSERTing` the text.

`escapeUtf8()` only complicates the situation; no function should be needed there.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your answer. One problem I have is that I don't have control over how the data is stored, since it is a 3rd party WordPress plugin.

Comment: Here is my complete comment (those 5 minute edit limit we have for comments....):    

Thanks Rick for your answer. One problem I have is that I don't have control over how the data is stored, since it is a 3rd party WordPress plugin. What I did was to use the STRINGDECODE function that I found here (look at Joni's answer): [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062330/mysql-decode-unicode-to-utf-8-function) and I "reversed" the process. Instead of escaping the column with "ñ" (or accented letters, etc.) from table A, I unescaped  the escaped columns in table B with STRINGDECODE.